# Piping my Python Program through another program

Tags: python

I'm trying to make program using Python.

I want to be able to pipe program through another program:

```
" #EXAMPLE " ./my_python | another programme "
```

Here is the code I have so far.

This code saves output to file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os,   random,   string
# This is not my own code
''' As far asi know, It belongs to NullUserException. Was found on stackoverflow.com'''
length = 8
chars = string.ascii_letters.upper()+string.digits
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))
# my code

file_out = open('newRa.txt','w') # Create a 'FILE' to save Generated Passwords
list1=[]
while len(list1) < 100000:
    list1.append(''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))

for item in list1:
    file_out.write('%s\n' % item)
file_out.close()


file_out1=open('test.txt','w')

for x in list1:
    file_out1.write('%s\n' %x[::-1])
```

This is the code I have trying to pipe it through another program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,string,random,sys
length = 8
chars = string.ascii_letters.upper()+string.digits
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

keep=[]
keep1=[]
while len(keep)<1000:
    keep.append(''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))

print '\n',keep[::-1]

for x in keep:
    keep1.append(x[::-1])

while len(keep1) < 1000:
    print keep1
```

I have tried chmod and using the script as a executable.

Comment: If you are basically trying to get output from one script/program to other then why not import and use its functions or something similarly simple.

Comment: Since you've answered your own question below, you should close it.

Comment: Yeh, I will close it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry for my lack of google search.

sys.stdout is the answer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,string,random,sys
length = 8
chars = string.ascii_letters.upper()+string.digits
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

keep=[]

while len(keep)<1000:
   keep = (''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))

   print sys.stdout.write(keep)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I stripped my code down (as it makes it a lot faster, But I'm getting this when  execute 
my code........
P5DBLF4KNone

DVFV3JQVNone

CIMKZFP0None

UZ1QA3HTNone

How do I get rid of the 'None' on the end?

What I have done to cause this ?

```
Should This Be A Seperate Question??
```